# SQL: How to parse a string only where certain character patterns exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm aware of using various functions like `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX`, but only for a single "spot" in a string. What I'm needing to do is parse out the characters of a string that exist between a `<` and `>`. For example:

```
<ul><li>Good afternoon,<br /><br />Please see the NDC number listed on the attached delivery ticket.<br /><br />Best regards,<br /><br />Rebecca Lawrence<br />Clinical Pharmacist<br /> <br /> <br /><br />From: Merino,Jason L <JLMerino@email.com> <br />Sent: Monday, September 12, 2022 1:17 PM<br />To: YYY <Pharmacy@email.com><br />Subject: NDC number<br /><br /><br />Hello! Could I please get the NDC number for Lewis Trantham's ID number 24628 medication? I just received it and it is not listed.  <br /> <br /> <br />Thank you!<br />Jason Merino<br />Office Coordinator<br />Specialty Clinic of City<br />(555) 555-5555</li></ul>
```

So it could be `<br>`, `<br />`, `<[email_address]>`, etc. Given the range of possibility of text that could exist here, I have no idea how to go about removing these bits of characters. As stated, I'm only aware of how to do this when the string is much more predictable. And this is stored as a `VARCHAR` by the way.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want the actual text.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '<ul><li>Good afternoon,<br /><br />Please see the NDC number listed on the attached delivery ticket.<br /><br />Best regards,<br /><br />Rebecca Lawrence<br />Clinical Pharmacist<br /> <br /> <br /><br />From: Merino,Jason L <JLMerino@email.com> <br />Sent: Monday, September 12, 2022 1:17 PM<br />To: YYY <Pharmacy@email.com><br />Subject: NDC number<br /><br /><br />Hello! Could I please get the NDC number for Lewis Trantham''s ID number 24628 medication? I just received it and it is not listed.  <br /> <br /> <br />Thank you!<br />Jason Merino<br />Office Coordinator<br />Specialty Clinic of City<br />(555) 555-5555</li></ul>'

Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'>','<')
```

**Results**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       Good afternoon,
2       Please see the NDC number listed on the attached delivery ticket.
3       Best regards,
4       Rebecca Lawrence
5       Clinical Pharmacist
6       From: Merino,Jason L 
7       Sent: Monday, September 12, 2022 1:17 PM
8       To: YYY 
9       Subject: NDC number
10      Hello! Could I please get the NDC number for Lewis Trantham's ID number 24628 medication? I just received it and it is not listed.  
11      Thank you!
12      Jason Merino
13      Office Coordinator
14      Specialty Clinic of City
15      (555) 555-5555
```

**The TVF if Intrested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delim1 varchar(100),@Delim2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                  ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
            From  ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delim1,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>').query('.'))) as A(XMLData)
            Cross Apply XMLData.nodes('x') AS B(i)
          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1

)
```

**Update ... One Line**

```
Select string_agg(RetVal,' ') within group (order by retseq)  
  From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'>','<')
```

Comment: Correct. I'll need to put it all on one line, but I think I can manage that. Thank you!

Comment: string_agg is exactly what I was going to try lol I recently discovered that gem, glad to hear I was on the right path.

Comment: Select string_agg(RetVal,' ') within group (order by retseq)  From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'>','<')

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have some kind of XHTML data. However it is not properly escaped. If it was, you could use SQL Server's XQuery to parse it. For example:

```sql
DECLARE @html xml = N'<ul><li>Good afternoon,<br /><br />Please see the NDC number listed on the attached delivery ticket.<br /><br />Best regards,<br /><br />Rebecca Lawrence<br />Clinical Pharmacist<br /> <br /> <br /><br />From: Merino,Jason L &lt;JLMerino@email.com&gt; <br />Sent: Monday, September 12, 2022 1:17 PM<br />To: YYY &lt;Pharmacy@email.com&gt;<br />Subject: NDC number<br /><br /><br />Hello! Could I please get the NDC number for Lewis Trantham''s ID number 24628 medication? I just received it and it is not listed.  <br /> <br /> <br />Thank you!<br />Jason Merino<br />Office Coordinator<br />Specialty Clinic of City<br />(555) 555-5555</li></ul>'

SELECT @html.query('for $t in //text() return concat($t, "
")').value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
```

Returns this

```
Good afternoon,
Please see the NDC number listed on the attached delivery ticket.
Best regards,
Rebecca Lawrence
Clinical Pharmacist
From: Merino,Jason L <JLMerino@email.com>
Sent: Monday, September 12, 2022 1:17 PM
To: YYY <Pharmacy@email.com>
Subject: NDC number
Hello! Could I please get the NDC number for Lewis Trantham's ID number 24628 medication? I just received it and it is not listed.
Thank you!
Jason Merino
Office Coordinator
Specialty Clinic of City
(555) 555-5555
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/qhTVfDTj)